# Calculus of Variations, Noether's Theorem, need help understanding and solving this problem

Tags: calculus-of-variations, symmetry, invariance

I have been given the following problem:

Investigate whether the functional $I=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}t\dot{x}^2dt$ is invariant under the transformation $\bar{t}=t+\epsilon$ and $\bar{x}=x$, with $\epsilon$ being an arbitrary constant.

All I have so far is the formula:
$$
L(\bar{t},\bar{x},\bar{\dot{x}})d\bar{t}=L(t,x,\dot{x})dt+d\Phi(t,x,\alpha_s)\\
$$with$$
\Phi(t,x,\alpha_s)=\Phi_s(t,x)\alpha_s
$$Where $\alpha_s$ is the transformation parameter.

I am also given: The Function $\Phi_s$ can also be zero, in which case we have invariance in its usual meaning.

So, am I correct in saying that in order for me to investigate whether or not the functional is invariant, I need to solve for $I$ and $\bar{I}$, with $\bar{I}=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(\bar{t},\bar{x},\bar{\dot{x}})d\bar{t}$?
In which case, this functional is not invariant because $\bar{t}$ has an arbitrary constant, whilst $t$ does not.

Comment: Better to ask it in physics stack.

Answer (score 1):

Well, given a [variational problem](https://ajpancollantes.github.io/%E2%99%BE%EF%B8%8F%20CONCEPTS/variational%20problem.md.html)
$$
J[x(t)]=\int_{\Omega}L(t,x(t),\frac{dx}{dt}(t))dt
$$
a Noether symmetry or divergence symmetry is a is a one-parameter [local group of transformations](https://ajpancollantes.github.io/%E2%99%BE%EF%B8%8F%20CONCEPTS/local%20group%20of%20transformations.md.html)
$$
t'=t'(t,x,s)\quad \quad x'=x'(t,x,s)
$$
such that
$$
L\left(t',x',\dot{x}'\right)dt'=L\left(t,x,\dot{x}\right)dt+d\Phi(t,x,s).
$$

It is the same that you have written. But I don't get why you use $\epsilon$ for the parameter and then change to the strange $\alpha_s$.

To see that your transformation is not a Noether symmetry, observe that $\bar{\dot{x}}=\dot{x}$ and then
$$
L(\bar{t},\bar{x},\bar{\dot{x}})d\bar{t}=\bar{t}\bar{\dot{x}}^2d\bar{t}=(t+\epsilon) \dot{x}^2 dt=
$$
$$
=t\dot{x}^2 dt+\epsilon\dot{x}^2dt=L(t,x,\dot{x})dt+\epsilon\dot{x}^2dt,
$$
and it can be shown that the $\epsilon\dot{x}^2dt\neq d \Phi$ for any $\Phi$, since
$
\epsilon\dot{x}^2dt
$
is not closed.